# Myob to Sql database

Tags: sql, myob

I use MYOB and a MySQL database where I store my business data. I want to enter data in to my MYOB database and at the end of the day sync the MYOB database with my MySQL database. I don't know if this is possible, just need some guidance. So for example, if i enter order details on MYOB and sync the two databases i want that order details to be in my MySQL database. Is this possible? if so how can I do it? I have heard about an ODBC driver, but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Which region and version of MYOB are you working with?

Both Australia and New Zealand AccountRight v19.x applications provide an ODBC driver, more information on MYOB ODBC can be found here http://developer.myob.com/resources/odbc-driver/ including a link to the user guides.

If your using the AccountRight Live platform, there is a REST based API available to consume, might be worth checking out MYOB's developer portal http://developer.myob.com/

Integrating your MySQL database with your company data will depend on which platform of MYOB you are using.

Hope this helps.